# Open containing folder crash

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, 64-bit, crash, utorrent

When I click "open containing folder" in either utorrent or chrome the application will crash.  Anyone have any ideas as to whats causing this or how I could trouble shoot it?  It just started happening two days ago and as far as I'm aware I haven't made any changes to my system in this time.

Windows 7 x64 ultimate

Comment: Did you recently change the folder where chome/uTorrent downloads to?

Comment: No.  Nothing changed, it just started happening.

Comment: Do you have application dumps of the crash? Check the event log.